# which I should use python or c++?

Tags: ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to make robot in hobby, but in the first place I wondering what I should use as language.

I read that python is slow in motion than by c++.
How fetal It slowness is in actual and in future Is will not it disadvantage fix?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311746/which-i-should-use-python-or-c++?/) by [fusiana](https://answers.ros.org/users/39255/fusiana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-01-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-01-01**:
Whichever you're more comfortable with

**Comment by [Farid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25360/farid/) on 2019-01-02**:
ROS wiki provides pretty educational tutorials for both c++ and python. It is just the matter of which language you've got experience or comfortable with, either with syntax or compilation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The biggest factor to influence your choice as has been said is which language you're most comfortable with. If you're relatively new to both languages I would highly recommend python, the C++ code that is used when using ROS is quite advanced using many complex features of the language.

Another thing that should be considered is that the ROS python API is slightly more restrictive than the C++ API. If you're getting started with ROS and working on hobby projects then this limitation of python will probably not effect you, but it's worth bearing in mind if you move onto more advanced projects.

Regarding your question about speed. The speed of python will only effect you if you're writing your own complex algorithms in python. Using the python API all the ROS functions will still be executed using fast compiled C++ versions, only your own code will be executed using the python interpreter.

Hope this helps you make and informed choice.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2